# Statusbar not defined error in ionic?

Tags: ionic-framework

I am getting statusbar not defined error in ionic !
i have already installed cordova status bar plugin,

```
0     811629   error    ReferenceError: StatusBar is not defined
at http://localhost:8100/js/directives.js:23:33
at Scope.$digest (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:30239:23)
at Scope.$apply (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:30503:24)
at http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:32332:36
at completeOutstandingRequest (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:19194:10)
at http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:19470:7
```

1     811642   error    ReferenceError: StatusBar is not defined
    at http://localhost:8100/js/directives.js:23:33
    at Scope.$digest (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:30239:23)
    at Scope.$apply (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:30503:24)
    at http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:32332:36
    at completeOutstandingRequest (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:19194:10)
    at http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:19470:7

Comment: are you running in real device or browser?

Comment: Running it in browser

Comment: you have to run on real device

Comment: Thank you for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since statusbar is not defined on browsers, I use this to avoid this error:

```
  if(ionic.Platform.isWebView()) {
    $cordovaStatusbar.styleHex('#FF0000'); //Do what you want
  }
```

`isWebView` is `true` if you run on a virtual device